# sha1 in php not storing properly in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sha1

I use the following code to store a password into mysql

```
    if (!$errors) {
    // include the connection file
    require_once('connection.inc.php');
    $conn = dbConnect('write');
    // create a salt using the current timestamp
    $salt = time();
    // encrypt the password and salt
    $pwd = sha1($password, $salt);
    echo $pwd;
    // prepare SQL statement
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (username, salt, pwd)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
    $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    // bind parameters and insert the details into the database
    $stmt->bind_param('sis', $username, $salt, $pwd);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->affected_rows == 1) {
        $success = "$username has been registered. You may now log in.";
    } elseif ($stmt->errno == 1062) {
        $errors[] = "$username is already in use. Please choose another username.";
        } else {
            $errors[] = 'Sorry, there was a problem with the database.';
        }

}
```

The password field, pwd, is defined as CHAR 40. When I examine it I see that it contains the following:

```
ƒ7Ž{9‰ù|EòsŒs”ºþ
```

no matter what password I enter. Naturally, this doesn't compare to the password when I try to login looking at it with this code:

```
    require_once('connection.inc.php');
$conn = dbConnect('read');
// get the username's details from the database
$sql = 'SELECT salt, pwd FROM users WHERE username = ?';
// initialize and prepare  statement
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql);
// bind the input parameter
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
// bind the result, using a new variable for the password
$stmt->bind_result($salt, $storedPwd);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetch();
// encrypt the submitted password with the salt
// and compare with stored password
if (sha1($password . $salt) == $storedPwd) {
    $_SESSION['authenticated'] = 'Jethro Tull';
    // get the time the session started
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    session_regenerate_id();
    header("Location: $redirect");
    exit;
} else {
    // if no match, prepare error message
    echo "  pwd " . $password;
    echo "  salt " . $salt;
    echo "  sha1 " . sha1($password . $salt);
    echo "  St. pwd " . $storedPwd;
    $error = 'Invalid username or password';
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a simple typo where you have written a comma (`,`) instead of a dot (`.`) when inserting your data to your database.

```
// encrypt the password and salt
$pwd = sha1($password, $salt);
```

Compare this to where you generate the hashsum when validating your password:

```
// encrypt the submitted password with the salt
// and compare with stored password
if (sha1($password . $salt) == $storedPwd) {
```

Since the two have very different meanings a mistake that small will have huge consequences overall.

You wanted to form a new string consisting of `$password` plus `$salt` but instead you are now giving `sha1` two arguments instead of one.

The second argument to `sha1` controls what kind of data the function will return, plaintext (if false, default) vs raw data (if true).

Comment: I don't see where this would apply. Could you please quote the code.

Comment: sorry, I see what you mean. You are so right. I must be getting blind. I copied the code and mistook a . for a ,

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is your only problem but

```
 $pwd = sha1($password, $salt);
```

is not how you use the `sha1` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php

`time()` will always evaluate to `TRUE` and thus you're inserting a raw binary format into your char password field. Causing the issue that you're seeing.

What you probably want to do is

```
 $pwd = sha1($password . $salt);
                       ^
```

Comment: The time() seems to be going in ok.

Comment: @Geoff - any integer != 0 in php evaluates to `TRUE` your time is being evaluated as `TRUE` for the second parameter of the `sha1` function. Making it return binary instead of the string that you're expecting and causing the password problem. What you probably wanted to do was `sha1($password . $salt)`

Answer (score 0):

sha1 returns the binary hash by default, which you're storing in a char field - char fields are subject to charset translation, which means mysql is mangling the hash. Convert the field to a binary/varbinary instead, which are NOT subject to charset translation

Comment: I have tried storing it in a BLOB field with similar poor results. How would I convert it to binary. I have tried the following: 'function hex2bin($h)
  {
  if (!is_string($h)) return null;
  $r='';
  for ($a=0; $a<strlen($h); $a+=2) { $r.=chr(hexdec($h{$a}.$h{($a+1)})); }
  return $r;
  }
' without success.

Comment: my bad, it's actually not the default, but you're passing in 2 args, and the second is actually the binary flag. the $salt field is seen as a binary true, forcing the binary return.